# Multiple Devices Authentiaction and SigningOut Mechanism

Tags: java, mobile, redis, architecture, jwt

I am designing a microservice and want it to be stateless. For that I dont want to use JWT as there are some security issues in libraries like null algorithms.My design is to have a common session store[like a cache]. For this I will have encryption algorithm to encrypt my uid. 
But my question is if I want to invalidate a user, say for logout mechanism I want the user to be logged in web but logged out of mobile how do I do that. And let the user have multiple devices how do I have to approach this case.

And how can I protect my token/cookie from session hijacking and please help me if there is any security flaw in my design. I keep on reading multiple blogs but all these questions are freaking me out for going forward and cant judge myself if my design is good.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement a service, that uses JWT and stateless if you want to log out from only one session (device). But if you use a Redis cache for common sessions your server will not be stateless by definition. What is your aim by being stateless?

Comment: My thought is to implement common authentication module for multiple microservices. And authentication module should also not hold any session information except check in cache for session object, so the session and service are decoupled and we can spin as many containers as we need or maintain recovery copy for the session cache. My doubt is what would be the schema or object model for multi device session maintenance, have to look into that